# How to install spring-boot-starter-security dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I am reading a tutorial on "Building Microservices with Spring", however, I can't find "spring-boot-starter-security" dependency - I am using Spring Tool Suite 3.8.3

Any guidance on how to install this dependency will be highly appreciated.

PS: I am new to Java and SpringFramework

[Maven dependency management picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KIsH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find your pom.xml, this is the file where all your dependencies are managed.

You can find a file in the Spring Tool Suite, by going to the search menu and d selecting file. You simply then need to enter "pom.xml" in the "File name patterns (seperated by comma):" field and press search.

You then can add the dependency like this in the `<dependencies> </dependencies>` element of the xml file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.M3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. That worked for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You could also right-click on the pom.xml file and go to "Spring -> Edit Starters" and select the one for spring security there. It adds that spring boot starter dependency to your pom for you.